# Python script to replace Path Variable in google sheet

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I want to write a Python script that appends a variable in google sheets :

Example Sheet:

```
Variable_1      Variable_2           Variable_3     
 A               ABC             /Home/Data/ggg/K.jpg
 B               PQR             /Home/Data/ggg/L.jpg 
 C               ABC             /Home/Data/ggg/M.jpg
```

I want to write a script in Python Programming language that replaces /Home/Data/ggg in Variable_3 with a path of my choice. (eg:/System/User/desktop/K.jpg)

Side Note:

My Script already establishes a connection with Google drive and Google sheets where the file lies.

Thank you

Comment: Is python tag relevant here?

Comment: No!!! but even if someone from the python community can provide the logic that can help.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming your sheet is a pandas dataframe

```
df['Variable_3'] = df['Variable_3'].str.replace('/Home/Data/ggg', path)
```

Comment: instead of guessing you can ask in comments section